# Row count after applying AutoFilter in Excel

Tags: c#

I am using the below piece of code to get the Row Count from an Excel file after applying AutoFilter method. But it always returns me 1 as Row count. Please help

```
Excel.Range rngFilter = (Excel.Range)applicationObject.get_Range("Staffing", Type.Missing);
rngFilter.AutoFilter(1, "Transition", XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, Type.Missing, true);
Excel.Range rngResult = rngFilter.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing);
MessageBox.Show(rngResult.Rows.Count.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this (as an example)

```
Excel.Range rngFilter = this.Application.get_Range("A1:A14", missing);
rngFilter.AutoFilter(1, "Transition", Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, missing, true);
Excel.Range rngResult = rngFilter.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, missing);
MessageBox.Show(rngFilter.Rows.Count.ToString());
```

and found it working. The output being 14.

You may also look into [Worksheet.AutoFilter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.autofilter%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Hope this will help you.